# How can move an object from one cell to other cell in c#

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<grid>
    <Image Name="i1" Source="king.jpg" Grid.row ="4" Grid.Column="1" 
        PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="im_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" ></Image>
</grid>
```

I know when image is clicked, `im_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` function is invoked. Now I want
to keep this image in other `cell(lets in row 2, col 4)`. Please if anyone can help to write this function `im_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Grid.SetRow(i1, 2);
Grid.SetColumn(i1, 4);
```